# ERROR! 'notify' is not a valid attribute for a Play

Tags: ansible, devops, playback, ansible-inventory

I am trying to install LAMP using Ansible-playbook. But I am getting the error[as shown in image]

The code that I had used for playbook is as follows:-

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
- name: Install httpd
   yum:
   name: httpd
   state: present
   notify: 
   - restart apache
- name: starting httpd service
   service:
   name: httpd
   enabled: yes
   state: started
- name: Installing php packages
   yum:
   name: "{{ item }}"
   state: present
  with_items:
  - php
  - php-mysql
  - php-pdo
  - php-gd
  - php-mbstring
  notify:
 -restart apache 
 handlers:
- name: restart apache
  service:
    name: httpd
    state: restarted
```

[Error in image format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slyYW.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Your indenting is incorrect. This should work:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Install httpd
      yum:
        name: httpd
        state: present
      notify: 
        - restart apache

    - name: starting httpd service
      service:
         name: httpd
         enabled: yes
         state: started

    - name: Installing php packages
      yum:
        name: "{{ item }}"
        state: present
      with_items:
        - php
        - php-mysql
        - php-pdo
        - php-gd
        - php-mbstring
      notify:
        - restart apache 

  handlers:
    - name: restart apache
      service:
        name: httpd
        state: restarted
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try as below. I think indention is the problem here.

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Install httpd
    yum:
     name: httpd
     state: present
    notify: "restart apache"
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution is as follows:

```
---
- hosts: all
  become: yes
  tasks:
  - name: Install httpd
    yum:
     name: httpd
     state: present
 - name: starting httpd service
   service:
    name: httpd
    enabled: yes
    state: started
- name: Installing php packages
    yum:
    name: "{{ item }}"
    state: present
  with_items:
   - php
   - php-mysql
   - php-pdo
   - php-gd
   - php-mbstring
  notify:
   - restart httpd
handlers:
  - name: restart httpd
   service:
    name: httpd
    state: restarted
```

[Solution in image form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9bujK.jpg)